# Getting the value of a listbox to dynamically change with worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, userform, worksheet

How can I get the value of a listbox in a userform to dynamically change when the user changes the value of a another list box in the same userform. The main portion that is giving me trouble is lstMonth. The value of lstMonth should equal the months, which correlate to the data in different sheets that will show in the first listbox. I will provide a picture of the form and data so that this all makes more since.[image]

**Code**

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub cmdCalc_Click()
    'declare variables and assign address to rngData variable
    Dim strId As String, intRow As Integer, intNumSales As Integer, curSales As Currency
    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = Application.Workbooks("t13-ex-e4d.xls").Worksheets("jan").Range("a3").CurrentRegion
    'assign selected list box item to strId variable
    strId = lstId.Value
    'locate first occurrence of ID
    intRow = 2
    Do Until rngData.Cells(RowIndex:=intRow, columnindex:=4).Value = strId
        intRow = intRow + 1
    Loop
    'accumulate and count salesperson's sales, stop when loop encounters different ID
    Do While rngData.Cells(RowIndex:=intRow, columnindex:=4).Value = strId
        curSales = curSales + rngData.Cells(RowIndex:=intRow, columnindex:=3).Value
        intNumSales = intNumSales + 1
        intRow = intRow + 1
    Loop
    'display appropriate amount
    If optTotal.Value = True Then
        lblAnswer.Caption = Format(expression:=curSales, Format:="currency")
    Else
        lblAnswer.Caption = Format(expression:=curSales / intNumSales, Format:="currency")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    'close custom dialog box
    Unload frmSalesCalc

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

lstMonth.Value = Application.Workbooks("T13-EX-E4D.xls").ActiveSheet.Range("b3").CurrentRegion


End Sub
```

Comment: i don't really understand the question, what should be in the month listbox ? all months there are, or all months in which a salesperson has sales ?

Comment: The months list box should be the same as the names of all worksheets in the workbook. Right now there are 3 (Feb, Mar, April) However if someone were to add May it would need to automatically put may in the listbox. Once that is working the list box to the left of months should change to the sales ID that is on the worksheet that is selected. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the form open fill the month listbox with all avaible sheets

```
     ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
     Dim Current As Worksheet

     ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
     For Each Current In Worksheets

        ' Insert your code here.
        ListBox_Month.AddItem Current.Name
     Next
```

The rest is basicaly to fill the other listbox if the month List is clicked, with all the avaible id's. So in the Listbox_Change Method you Need something like this:

```
Dim sales_ids as Variant 
sales_ids = UniquesFromRange(Worksheets(Listbox_Month.value).Range(D))

Function UniquesFromRange(rng As Range)
 Dim d As Object, c As Range, tmp
 Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
 For Each c In rng.Cells
   tmp = Trim(c.Value)
   If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
        If Not d.Exists(tmp) Then d.Add tmp, 1
   End If
 Next c
 UniquesFromRange = d.keys
End Function
```

Now you have all the id's, fill them in the second listbox, and voila, the rest should be clear, but just ask if you still have questions