# How to create dynamic dependent list in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create two dropdown lists in Excel. The second one is dependent on the first one. So I have the dynamic data (I will have constantly changing vehicles and engines):

[image]

The first dropdown I want is to display the vehicles. The second one will display the engines available for that vehicle.

I have looked through the internet and the suggestion is to create a Name Range for each vehicle, but I was hoping to have a better solution like a VlookUp that would return a list.

I am using the following to get the vehicles and engines into a Name Range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Dim lRow As Integer

lRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B3:B" & lRow).Name = "VehList"

Range("C3:C" & lRow).Name = "CalList"
```

Comment: so something likes this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415648/getting-the-value-of-a-listbox-to-dynamically-change-with-worksheets/36435585#36435585

Answer (score 2):

For simple cases, you do not need *VBA* or Defined names.

Consider:

[image]

We have a drop-down in **A1** to select either *fruit* or *dog* or *cat*.  We want to setup a dropdown in **A2** to display the proper sublist.

We click on **A2** and Setup *DV* with the *List* option and the following formula in *Source:*

```
=IF(A1="fruit",C1:C4,IF(A1="dog",D1:D4,E1:E4))
```

[image]

This is for only three options in in the primary pull-down.  If your case has too many options in the primary pull-down, the nesting of the ***IF()*** may be a limitation.

Comment: Thanks, but my lists are always changing their values. I am not getting on how to apply your suggestion. And they are always in the format I showed.

Answer (score 2):

Using a reference cell name, a dynamic reference cell name and some data validation lists, we can accomplish this...

An example table:

```
Vehicle                     Engines                     
V01     V01E01  V01E02  V01E03  V01E04  V01E05  V01E06  V01E07
V02     V02E01  V02E02  V02E03  V02E04  V02E05  V02E06  
V03     V03E01  V03E02  V03E03  V03E04          
V04     V04E01  V04E02  V04E03  V04E04  V04E05      
V05     V05E01  V05E02  V05E03  V05E04  V05E05  V05E06  
V06     V06E01  V06E02  V06E03  V06E04  V06E05  V06E06  V06E07
V07     V07E01  V07E02  V07E03  V07E04          
V08     V08E01  V08E02
```

Vehicle types stated vertically and their dependent engines horizontally

I named the cell that has 'Vehicle' written in it as 'VE', then created the first dropdown list using data validation in Cell $C$12 using the following formula:

> =OFFSET(VE,1,0,COUNTA(OFFSET(VE,1,0,10,1)),1)

I then created a dynamic named range called 'VItem' which had the following formula:

> =INDEX(OFFSET(VE,1,0,10,1),MATCH($C$12,OFFSET(VE,1,0,10,1),0))

VItem is therefore assigned as the cell containing the vehicle specified in the first dropdown box

For the second dropdown box I then used data validation again with the following formula:

> =OFFSET(VItem,0,1,1,COUNTA(OFFSET(VItem,0,1,1,10)))

SOME NOTES: The lists are sized depending on how many non-blank cells are present within a specified range within the offsets (in this code a 10x1 set of cells is used). As it auto-sizes, the vehicle list should be contiguous vertically and the engines listed horizontally should again be contiguous

Vehicle names would need to be unique so 'VItem' is correctly assigned

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to get the first dropdown list working but not the second one. I think it is because you are displaying the Engines horizontally and I need it to be vertically as I've shown in the question. Could you please help me modifying the formula? Thanks