Dependent dropbox on excel userform

I would like to change the the dropdown box "Service" ( values in Sheets"Lookup" columns G,H,I) to depending dropdown based on values from dropdown box "Department" ( values in Sheets"Staff" column A) and if possible generate unique ID for new record being added....

Module
Option Explicit

Public Function GetRange() As Range

    ' Get the data range from the Staff worksheet
    Set GetRange = shStaff.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    ' remove the header from the range by moving the range down one row and
    ' then removing the last row.
    Set GetRange = GetRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetRange.Rows.Count - 1)

End Function

' Delete the row from the staff worksheet
Public Sub DeleteSelectedRow(ByVal row As Long)
    ' Offset moves the range a given number of rows
    shStaff.Range("A2").Offset(row).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

' Return the list of countries from the Lookup table
Public Function GetServices() As Variant
    GetServices = shLookup.ListObjects("tbCountry").DataBodyRange.Value
End Function

' Return the list of departments from the Lookup table
Public Function GetDepartments() As Variant
    GetDepartments = shLookup.ListObjects("tbDepartment").DataBodyRange.Value
End Function

' Create the ID for a new record
Public Function GetNewID() As Long
    GetNewID = 1 + WorksheetFunction.Max(shStaff.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.columns(1))
End Function



formStaffDetailsEdit
Option Explicit



Private m_currentRow As Long

Public Property Let currentRow(ByVal newCurrentRow As Long)
    m_currentRow = newCurrentRow
End Property

' USERFORM EVENTS
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call FillComboboxes
    Call LoadData
End Sub

Private Sub buttonClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub buttonUpdate_Click()
    Call WriteDataToSheet
End Sub

' HELPER FUNCTION/SUBS
Public Sub FillComboboxes()

    ' Fill the comboboxes
    Me.comboService.List = GetServices()
    Me.comboDepartment.List = GetDepartments()
    
End Sub

' Load data from the worksheet to the controls
Public Sub LoadData()
    
    ' Offset moves the range the numbers of rows specified by m_currentRow
    With shStaff.Range("A2").Offset(m_currentRow)
        textboxID.Value = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        textboxFirstname.Value = .Cells(1, 2).Value
        textboxLastname.Value = .Cells(1, 3).Value
        comboService.Value = .Cells(1, 4).Value
        OptionFulltime.Value = IIf(.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Full-time", True, False)
        OptionParttime.Value = IIf(.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Part-time", True, False)
        comboDepartment.Value = .Cells(1, 6).Value
    End With
    
End Sub

' Write the data to the worksheet from the controls
Private Function WriteDataToSheet()

    If MsgBox("Do you want to save this record?", vbYesNo, "Save record") = vbYes Then

        ' Offset moves the range by the numbers of rows specified by m_currentRow
        With shStaff.Range("A2").Offset(m_currentRow)

            ' copy the data to the controls
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = textboxID.Value
            .Cells(1, 2).Value = textboxFirstname.Value
            .Cells(1, 3).Value = textboxLastname.Value
            .Cells(1, 4).Value = comboService.Value
            .Cells(1, 5).Value = IIf(OptionFulltime.Value = True, "Full-time", "Part-time")
            .Cells(1, 6).Value = comboDepartment.Value

        End With

    End If

End Function

formStaffDetailsNew
Option Explicit




' USERFORM EVENTS
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call CreateNewID
    Call InitializeControls
End Sub

Private Sub buttonClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

' Save the data
Private Sub buttonSave_Click()
        
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save this record?:", vbYesNo, "Save record") = vbYes Then
        ' Add the new staff member details to the worksheet
        Call WriteDataToSheet
        ' Remove data from textboxes
        Call EmptyTextboxes
        ' Create the new ID for the staff member
        Call CreateNewID
    End If
    
End Sub

' HELPER FUNCTION/SUBS
Private Sub CreateNewID()
    textboxID.Value = GetNewID()
End Sub

' Save the record and clear the data from the controls
Private Function WriteDataToSheet()

    Dim newRow As Long
    With shStaff

        ' Get the first blank row of data
        newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
        
        ' Write the data
        .Cells(newRow, 1).Value = textboxID.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 2).Value = textboxFirstname.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 3).Value = textboxLastname.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 4).Value = comboService.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 5).Value = IIf(OptionFulltime.Value = True, "Full-time", "Part-time")
        .Cells(newRow, 6).Value = comboDepartment.Value

    End With

End Function

' Clear data from the textbox controls
Public Sub EmptyTextboxes()
    
    Dim c As Control
    ' Read through all the controls
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
            c.Value = ""
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

Public Sub InitializeControls()

    ' Fill the comboboxes and select the first item
    Me.comboService.List = GetServices()
    Me.comboService.ListIndex = 0
    Me.comboDepartment.List = GetDepartments()
    Me.comboDepartment.ListIndex = 0
    
    OptionFulltime.Value = True
    
End Sub


Appreciate any help....

Maybe used named ranges ("Plumbing", "Carpentry", etc.) for every department's services and then use those strings to access the list of services to populate the dropdown menu?

I have those depended ranges named but my coding skills are not good enough to connect it to master dropdown box....  :(

Assuming the named ranges as the same names as the departments ("Plumbing", "Carpentry", etc.), assign the selected one to a string variable (myRng for example), then get the data in the named range using Range(myRng)

You may want to review a previous answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36586662/3688861

What about OOP?
Let's create a department object with collection of services (insert new Class Module and name it cDepartment):
Option Explicit

Dim sDepName As String
Dim cServices As New Collection


Public Property Get DepName() As String
    DepName = sDepName
End Property

Public Property Let DepName(sName As String)
    sDepName = sName
End Property

Public Property Get Services() As Collection
    Set Services = cServices
End Property

Public Property Set Services(oServices As Collection)
    Set cServices = oServices
End Property

Then add below code to your UserForm (change the names of controls according to your needs):
Option Explicit

Dim deps As New Collection


Private Sub CmbDepartments_Change()
    Dim dep As cDepartment, oSer As Variant
    
    Me.CmbServices.Clear
    
    Set dep = deps(Me.CmbDepartments.ListIndex + 1)
    For Each oSer In dep.Services
        Me.CmbServices.AddItem CStr(oSer)
    Next oSer
    
    Set dep = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wbk As Workbook, wsh As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long, r As Long
    Dim dep As cDepartment
    
    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsh = wbk.Worksheets(1)
    
    For c = 0 To 2
        r = 1
        Set dep = New cDepartment
        dep.DepName = wsh.Range("G" & r).Offset(ColumnOffset:=c)
        deps.Add dep
        Me.CmbDepartments.AddItem dep.DepName
        r = 2
        Do While wsh.Range("G" & r).Offset(ColumnOffset:=c) <> ""
            dep.Services.Add wsh.Range("G" & r).Offset(ColumnOffset:=c)
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Next c
    
    Set dep = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
End Sub

Result:

Try it.

code works very well , thank you. Dziekuje serdecznie za pomoc, pozdrawiam, Dariusz.

Would it be hard to add another level in next dropdown , let's say if values from column G would bring list from column K, L, M and col H from N, O, P, Q?
